# how do I get star rating in google search result underneath my site URL

Tags: php, html, code-snippets

I want to get them just with code. Not with google reviews cause people need to have a google account for that. I've looked on schema.org but i just don't get it.

so how do i get the stars in my snippet

Comment: This feature is well documented in google rich snippets documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippets

Answer (score 5):

You should use [AggregateRating](https://schema.org/AggregateRating) :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
    "name" : "My Company",
    "url" : "http://www.mycompany.com/",
    "telephone" : "(+33) 1 23 45 67 89",
    "email" : "info@mycompany.com",
    "address" : {
        "@type" : "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress" : "1 Rue de la Place",
        "addressLocality" : "Paris",
        "postalCode" : "75000"
    },
    "aggregateRating" : {
        "@type" : "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue" : "4.2",
        "bestRating" : "5",
        "ratingCount" : "100"
    },
    "openingHours": "Mo-Su 00:00-00:00"
}
</script>
```

The snippet above should be put just before the ending `</html>` tag, and should display a score of 4.2/5 based on 100 ratings

Comment: thanks, but how do people rate do i need to build something for that to ?
And the site is made in wordpress so i dont know if i can add the script.
can it also be done in html ? instead of java.

Comment: Yep, you can use the [HTML Markup](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_why). As for how to build your ratings, you could either develop a rating plug-in for your website and then extract the data, or use a third-party application such as [Verified Reviews](http://www.verified-reviews.co.uk/) or [eKomi](http://www.ekomi.com/us/)

Comment: and i want it in de snippet underneath my site url in the google search results not on the web page itself.

Comment: I know, but you have to use the schema.org snippet in order for Google to get your ratings.